# Problems getting an OpenCl example to build in MSVS 2012 express. Not finding header files but paths etc...seem fine

Tags: c, opencl, header-files, visual-studio-express

I just started learning C last month and I just installed Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012 this week; along with the AMD OpenCl SDK. I've followed the installation guides, searched around and everything seems to be setup properly, yet I still can't get this OpenCl example to build.

I'm trying to get an example to run that is in an OpenCL Programming guide book I downloaded from AMD. The problem 
I keep running into is that it doesn't seem to be able to locate the OpenCl header files.

```
"Error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'CL/cl_platform.h': No such file or directory 
c:\program files (x86)\amd app\include\cl\cl.h"
```

I checked the directory to make sure, and yep, the file is there.

For includes I have: 
    #include `<C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\include\CL\cl.h`

I've tried it as just:
    `#include <Cl\cl.h>` and `#include <Cl/cl.h>`

And the only time VS seems to find it is either with the full path, or as:
`#include <cl.h>`

Otherwise I get:
    `"Error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'CL\cl.h': No such file or directory"`

Here's what I have for environmental path variable:

```
AMDAPPSDKROOT     C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP

Path              C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86_64
```

And in VS in C/C++ under Additional Include Directories:

```
$(AMDAPPSDKROOT)\include
```

Under Linker Additional Library Directories:

```
$(AMDAPPSDKROOT)\lib\x86_64
```

Under Input as Additional Dependencies

```
OpenCL.lib
```

And here's the commandline output for the C/C++:

`/MP /GS /TC /Qpar /analyze /Wall /Gy /Zc:wchar_t /I"C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\include" /ZI /Gm /Od /Fd"Debug\vc110.pdb" /fp:precise /D "_MBCS" /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /RTC1 /GR /Gd /Oy- /MDd /openmp /Fa"Debug\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"Debug\" /Ot /Fp"Debug\OpenClPractice.pch"`

And the Linker:

`/OUT:"D:\Python\C\OpenClPractice\Debug\OpenClPractice.exe" /MANIFEST /NXCOMPAT /PDB:"D:\Python\C\OpenClPractice\Debug\OpenClPractice.pdb" /DYNAMICBASE "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib" "OpenCL.lib" /DEBUG /MACHINE:X86 /INCREMENTAL /PGD:"D:\Python\C\OpenClPractice\Debug\OpenClPractice.pgd" /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /ManifestFile:"Debug\OpenClPractice.exe.intermediate.manifest" /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /NOLOGO /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\lib\x86_64" /TLBID:1`

It all looks fine to me, but clearly it isn't or I wouldn't be having this problem. If anyone can help that'd be great.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you try to simply create a new Empty Project -> add example sources to project -> go to project properties; manually add `C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\include` to additional include directories and `C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\lib\x86` to additional library directories (preferably from the <Edit...> dialog) -> add `OpenCL.lib` to linker input -> build solution and see if it works? :P

Comment: (and `C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\lib\x86` (sic) instead of `C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\lib\x86_64` because the default build platform for an empty project is Win32)

Comment: Hey Elmov, that sort of seems to work. Or at least I'm not having the problem with it finding the whatever.h anymore. But I don't think it's working properly as now I have 46 errors, most of which seem to be of "Error C2065: 'context' : undeclared identifer". Error C2275: 'cl_program' : illegal use of this type as an expression" or Error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'program'

Comment: Ah, right. Try setting the `Compile As` option to `Compile as C++ code (/TP)` from the project properties -> C/C++ -> Advanced, and see if that works for you.

Comment: Works fine now for that example thanks! I tried it with another example, doing the same thing, and that gives different errors; see if I can figure that one out...Thanks for the help.

Comment: Figured it out! IT would appear the source I copied from had a different " than what VS wanted as ". You'd think it would have an error msg for that, but I suppose that would make things too easy...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To provide an aggregate of the discussion on the comments; it appears the problem was solved by simply creating a new, clean project, adding the relevant directories and linker input manually (without any environment variable expansions) via the *Project Properties* dialog.

As to the original problem.. I don't really know. The only thing in the command-line argstring that would have likely caused direct trouble was the `/TC` (compile as C89 code) switch, which was automatically "deduced" by Visual Studio based on the input source file extension (most likely `.c` in this case). Replacing `/TC` with `/TP` (compile as C++ code) should work.

Also, the example source has been said to possibly having used either “ (`U+201C`),  ” (`U+201D`) or even a ‟ (`U+201F`) as quotation mark glyphs instead of the correct " (`U+0022`), which will indeed cause trouble when pasted to the source explorer.